# fake columns with union and two inner joins?

Tags: sql, mysql

i've got this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT ACCOUNTS.INSTALLTIME, ACCOUNTS.HONAME, ACCOUNTS.ADDRESS, ACCOUNTS.CITY, ACCOUNTS.STATE, ACCOUNTS.ZIP, ACCOUNTS.JOBNUMBER, ACCOUNTS.INSTALLDATE, ACCOUNTS.RESULT, ACCOUNTS.NOTES, ACCOUNTS.SMNOTES, technicians.technumber, technicians.boardplacing 
FROM ACCOUNTS 
INNER JOIN technicians ON ACCOUNTS.INSTALLER = technicians.technumber) 
UNION 
(SELECT service.servicetime, service.Customername, service.address, service.city, service.state, service.zip, service.ID, service.serviceday, service.result, service.servicenotes, service.board, technicians.technumber, technicians.boardplacing
FROM service 
INNER JOIN technicians ON service.technician= technicians.technumber)
) as t WHERE t.INSTALLDATE = '$date' ORDER BY t.boardplacing
```

is there any way I can make a query similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT ACCOUNTS.INSTALLTIME, ACCOUNTS.HONAME, ACCOUNTS.ADDRESS, ACCOUNTS.CITY, ACCOUNTS.STATE, ACCOUNTS.ZIP, ACCOUNTS.JOBNUMBER, ACCOUNTS.INSTALLDATE, ACCOUNTS.RESULT, ACCOUNTS.NOTES, ACCOUNTS.SMNOTES, '' as priority, ACCOUNTS.PAFS, ACCOUNTS.upsell, ACCOUNTS.TERM, ACCOUNTS.MMRUPGRADE, ACCOUNTS.WARRANTY, ACCOUNTS.EFT, technicians.technumber, technicians.boardplacing 
FROM ACCOUNTS 
INNER JOIN technicians ON ACCOUNTS.INSTALLER = technicians.technumber) 
UNION 
(SELECT service.servicetime, service.Customername, service.address, service.city, service.state, service.zip, service.ID, service.serviceday, service.result, service.servicenotes, service.board, '', '', '', '', '', '', technicians.technumber, technicians.boardplacing
FROM service 
INNER JOIN technicians ON service.technician= technicians.technumber)
) as t WHERE t.INSTALLDATE = '$date' ORDER BY t.boardplacing
```

basically i need fake columns in my union. is there any way to pull that off with the joins? is there some other better way to do this?

Comment: As long as the number of columns in the union match, it should work.

Comment: the columns match up, however it still gives me:

supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: are all the fake columns your replacing with '' strings in the first query? database datatype should match

Comment: wow. yea, i thought the columns were the same amount but they were off by one field. thanks!

Comment: BTW are you sure you need union, would unoinall work? It's a lot faster if you know that results won't be duplicated betewen the two results sets.

Answer (score 5):

When I am writing a union query and need "fake" or "dummy" columns, I just use:

`NULL AS Fake`

So the whole query will look something like this;

```
SELECT A.CHEESE, A.BREAD, A.GARLIC, A.COST
FROM ACHEESETABLE A
WHERE A.BREAD = WHEAT

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL AS CHEESE, B.BREAD, NULL AS GARLIC, B.COST
FROM BCHEESYTABLE B
WHERE B.COST > 15
```

This way both queries have a `CHEESE` and `GARLIC` column, but `BCHEESYTABLE` does not contain the columns, `CHEESE` or `GARLIC`.  Doing it like this also allows different `WHERE` criteria for both queries, so in essence it is possible to have two different record population in the same query.